# What is a Vector

Tags: matlab

I am from C/C++ programming world and finding it difficult to understand what exactly is a Vector / Matrix in MATLAB - why are the not termed as array everywhere.

What is Vector in MATLAB and why it is not called or referenced as an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "MAT" in MATLAB is for Matrix, not Math. In MATLAB, basically everything you do is calculations with what you would call matrices / vectors in mathematical terms.

It is common to call a numeric array a matrix (or vector if it's 1xn), and other arrays for arrays. You'll see terms like cell array, which is an array of cells.

This way you can use mathematical terms when describing calculations with numerical arrays. For instance `inv` can be used to find the inverse of a matrix, instead of the inverse of a numeric array. (Btw, never use inv, it was just an example).

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is designed to use as "Matrix-Lab": a tool for numerically process linear-algebra objects such as vector and matrices. So, in terms of "data structures" it indeed works with n-dimensional arrays, but has special names for the special cases: "vector" for 1-d array and "matrix" for 2-d array.